# What is the best way to upload data to server and then store locally using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to do two things: upload some data to server and then save data to local database with returned id from server. What is the best way to do it with RxJava. I tired to do something like this but I guess it's not the best solution because of side effects in map and flatMap. I'm using `Retrofit` to communicate with server, `ObjectBox` as local database and ofcourse `RxJava2`

```
private fun saveMyData(data: MyData) =
        uploadToServer(data).flatMap {
                    saveToLocalRepository(it)
                }


private fun uploadToServer(data: MyData): Single<MyData> =
    dataApiService.uploadMyData(data).map { id: Long -> 
                data.copy(serverId = it)
            }

private fun saveToLocalRepository(data: MyData): Single<MyData> =
        localRepository.save(data).map{ id: Long -> 
            data.copy(id = it)
        }
```

Comment: Use Retrofit, It is best for Architecture Component and RxJava.

Comment: `the best way` there is nothing best in programming world. The is only what somebody may like, or dislike. It's called `opinion-based`